# Compare character with array

Tags: c, arrays

I want to make a program that counts the vowels in a sentence entered by the user.
For that compare a character that capitalizes with the vowel arrangement, but although they do not pulls error, do not type the correct output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>

//Program EJER004
int main(){
    char vowels[5] = {'A','E','I','O','U'};
    int count;
    char letter;

    count = 0;

    printf("Enter a phrase, ending with a point\n");

    do{
        letter=getchar();
        if (toupper(letter) == vowels[5]) /*attempt ask if is a vowel the letter introduced*/
           count++;     
    }while (letter != '.');

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("The number of vowels in the phrase introduced is% d", count);       
    getch(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no value at `vowels[5]`; your array is indexed from 0 to 4.  So, you invoke undefined behaviour and anything can happen.  You will either need to write a loop to search through the list of characters, or change the definition to `char vowels[] = "AEIOU";` and then use an appropriate string scan function to see whether the letter is in the list of vowels.

Answer (score 0):

It think the problem is the comparison `toupper(letter) == vowels[5]`? vowels[5] is always out of array, but other vowels aren't checked.
You would need to add a loop like:

```
char upr=toupper(letter);
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) 
  if(vowels[i]==c)
  { cont++;      
    break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write a small function for this comparison

```
int checkforVowels(char tobechecked)
{
  //this only get vowels in CAPSLOCK tho... so dont forget toupper
  char vowels[5] = {'A','E','I','O','U'};
  int hasvowel = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    if(tobechecked == vowels[i])
    {
      hasvowel = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  return hasvowel;
}
```

so you can have it like that

```
if(checkforVowels(toupper(letter))
```

HTH